# Uiimageview not showing in iPhone 6 and 6 plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, iphone-6

I have collection view with custom cell.

And in custom cell iPhone 6 and 6 plus Uiimageview is not showing. 
But when i am printing the frame its there.

```
NSLog(@"%f-%f-%f-%f",cell._image.frame.origin.x,cell._image.frame.origin.y,cell._image.frame.size.width,cell._image.frame.size.height);

Log - 
0.000000-0.000000-177.500000-168.000000
```

Cell Screenshot is -

[image]

Any suggestions what i am doing wrong...

Note - its working properly in iPad, iPhone 4,4s,5.

Comment: FYI - easier way to log a `CGRect`: `NSLog(@"image frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(cell._image.frame));`.

Comment: Did you check if the image view's image is actually set properly?

Comment: yes, image is set properly because its working in iPad, iPhone 4,4s,5...

Comment: Let me clarify. Did you check if the image view's image is actually set properly when running on an iPhone 6 or 6+? Update your question with relevant code showing how you set the image view's image.

Comment: My guess is it has no image loaded. For iPhone6+ could be down to it being @3x resolution. How do you load the images? BTW: You want to print the size of the image not the image view. So `cell._image.image.size.width,cell._image.image.size.height`.

Comment: I am showing image from url ... let me try to print image size.

Comment: yes image size also there - 178.000000-253.000000
 321.000000-168.000000
 321.000000-168.000000
 321.000000-168.000000
321.000000-168.000000
 178.000000-178.000000
 299.000000-168.000000
 253.000000-169.000000

Comment: The image could be hidden because the height and/or width of the cell itself is 0. Check the height and width of the cell and make sure the cell is visable.

Comment: Cell is showing all other contents, you can see in the attached image...

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if the image is even loaded.   For iPhone 6 (vs the working ones) it is looking for a file/resource of name  ImageName@2x.png

Its also possible your image view is setting alpha to zero (so image ends up just being white as background).   You may have something like this that you need to comment out (or switch on phone type) :

```
- (void) setAlpha:(float)alpha {
//    [super setAlpha:alpha];
}
```

Where is your image loaded from?  Maybe show that code too.   Maybe you have offsets that put the image off the display?